# Why won't this PrintTemporary[Dynamic[...]] expression work in a function?

Tags: functions

I found myself reusing this code all the time to monitor variables during execution, so I'm trying to make it into a function:

```
pdr[expr_, symbols_List: {}, interval_: \[Infinity]] := 
  PrintTemporary[
   Dynamic[Refresh[expr, TrackedSymbols :> symbols, 
     UpdateInterval -> interval]]];
```

But then when I try to use it, as with something like

```
s={};
pdr[s,{s},1];

Do[
    AppendTo[s,n];
    Pause[1];
,{n,3}]
```

it doesn't seem to work. If I paste in the exact same `PrintTemporary` line that the function is calling in place of my `pdr` function, it works as expected. It seems like there's some quirk of Mathematica I'm overlooking here, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `{s}` in `pdr[s, {s}, 1]` evaluates to `{{}}`.  So the `TrackedSymbols` option of `Refresh` does not see a list of symbols.

One fix:

```
Clear[s];
pdr[s, {s}, 1];
s = {};

Do[AppendTo[s, n];
 Pause[1];, {n, 3}]
```

Another:

```
ClearAll[pdr];
SetAttributes[pdr, HoldAll];
pdr[expr_, symbols_List: {}, interval_: \[Infinity]] :=
  Block[symbols,
   PrintTemporary[
    Dynamic[Refresh[expr, TrackedSymbols :> symbols, 
      UpdateInterval -> interval]]]
   ];
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks!